# replacing deprecated atl attribut

Tags: atl, visual-c++-2015

How should I replace deprecated atl code (Visual Studio 2015 warning C4467)?
The data structure is within a file DataType.h

```
    struct SData4
    {
        SData4() { Init(); }
        ~SData4() { Delete(); }
        void Init();
        void Delete();
        LPWSTR m_strSomething; 
        [string] LPWSTR m_strCode; 
    };
```

The IDL file contains method declerations using this structure as follows:

```
    // interface version 6.0
[
    object,
    uuid(...-.-.-.-.),
    helpstring("IData4 Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IData4 : IUnknown
{
    [helpstring("method SetData")] HRESULT SetData([in] long lLen, [in, size_is(lLen)] SData4* s);
};
```

What I don't get is, that there are `LPWSTR` definitions without `[string]` attribute within the same struct. And it has worked for a decade :/ The microsoft help page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8tesw2eh.aspx states that

> `[string]` Indicates that the one-dimensional char, wchar_t, byte, or equivalent array or the pointer to such an array must be treated as a string.

So I have to find a way to tell DCOM that this `WCHAR *` is a string. But why and how?

Ok, I found an indication within the book "Inside Distributed COM" from Guy and Henry Eddon. They state, that the `[string]` attribute allows the user to send strings without defining the actual string length. If the attribute is omitted, you have to implement memory management of this string using `CoTaskMemAlloc` and `CoTaskMemFree`.

Comment: I see no context, so it is a little bit difficult to answer. If it is just a MIDL keyword just remove it and add a correct matching idl file to the project.

Comment: After returning to the project, I fixed up the question context and added some research results found in the last month.

Answer (score 2):

To replace [`[string]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9a4wd1h.aspx) or another ATL attribute, the generic solution is to enable Expand Attributed Source option in project settings. Then, when building the code you will have a non-attributed C++ code where attribute processor expanded the attributes. Inspecting the expanded code you see what non-attributed code corresponds to what you had in first place.

Comment: This would really be helpful. Unfortunately it looks like the /Fx option is buggy. Setting this option, the expected .mrg.cpp/.h files are not created. Instead compile errors starting with "c2337 attribute not found" occur.

Comment: @RomanR.: should that be set in the newer VS versions or in the old one?